# Separating multiindex column to multiple rows under same multiindex header

Tags: pandas, multi-index

[image]

[image]

[image]

Below i have a pandas dataframe having multiindex, one level is "Address" and second level is (score,num,axis).All total one column.
Output i am looking as separate columns under 'Address' column index.

print(df.columns.tolist())

Comment: Added in the question.df.info() is very big but for your info its all "object " type

Comment: You think `df.xs('Address', axis=1, level=0)` ?

Comment: added in question

Comment: How was created `DataFrame` ? by `pd.read_csv` ? Then there is no `sep=','` ?

Comment: In latest picture all are in a single column.How dataframe created ? the value inside column was a result of string concat of values from two separate columns.

Comment: hmmm, so problem is all data are in one column instead in multiple columns? If yes, how was create both DataFrames used for `concat` ?

Comment: like Score is refered to '0.0', Not Applicable refers to 'False' and  PresetCommentQuestion and Mechanics feedback is blank.
"Concat"i meant i did df1 + ',' + df2 thats why above format came.

Comment: There is an microsoft excel operation called "text to columns".Can we do same by using pandas?

Comment: so problem is all data are in one column instead in multiple columns?

Comment: yes all data in one column and i want to separate in multiple columns under level = 0 header for e.g. under "Question-0".

Comment: So why is used `df1 + ',' + df2` if donr need joined values?

Comment: Yeah, previously "Score" columns and other columns are separated as different columns.I wanted to combine all under "Question-0" header.so did df1 + ' ' + df2

Answer (score 0):

The question is not exactly clear but from what i got, try this:

```
df.reset_index().set_index('Address')
```